# add where clause to datatables filtering

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

hi I am trying to a add a custom WHERE clause in my datatables server side processing file. I have managed to get it to work when the page loads but after filtering it ignores the where clause and returns all results.

code:

```
$sWhere = "WHERE customers_id= ".$customersId;
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out where to add the other WHERE clauses in order for it to work when beign filtered also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first line and add this at the end (after the `if` and `for`):

```
$sWhere .= ($sWhere ? ' AND ' : ' WHERE ') . 'customers_id = ' . $customersId;
```

Comment: just tried it and it just gets stuck at processing and gives a 500 error when i try searching

Comment: when i do a var_dump I am not able to get to the search because the json formating is wrong do to the extra var_dump info

Comment: @arrowill12 Sorry I see what I did wrong, it should have been `.=` in my answer. (updated)

Answer (score 0):

ended up solving it here is the solution:

```
$sWhere = "WHERE customers_id=".$customersId;
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ') AND customers_id='.$customersId;
    //var_dump($sWhere);
}
```

the code is needed in just those 2 locations

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/* LINE 86
    $sWhere = "";
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
        {
                $sWhere = "WHERE (";
                for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
                {
                        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
                }
                $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
                $sWhere .= " AND customer_id='".$_GET['customer_id']."'";
                $sWhere .= ')';
        }else{
                $sWhere = "WHERE customer_id='".$_GET['customer_id']."'";
        }
```

I hope that solves your purpose.